# React Hooks Form - onSubmit with data from useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, onsubmit

Hi :) I want to create checkout form with customer's address data, but onSubmit I would like to attach order data stored in useState (cartItems). For now, I've finished react hook form with onSubmit button that console.log only form inputs.
What is the best way to do that?

```
const Checkout = ({ emoneyPayment, setEmoneyPayment, cartItems }: CheckoutProps) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<Order>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with React Hooks Form and TypeScript, but in JS / React you could wrap it in another hook:

```
const Checkout = ({ emoneyPayment, setEmoneyPayment, cartItems }: CheckoutProps) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<Order>();

  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])

  // this function will be redefined every time cartItems or handleSubmit updates 
  const submitForm = useCallback(() => {
    handleSubmit(cartItems)
  }, [cartItems, handleSubmit])

  return <div onClick={submitForm}>Submit</div>
}
```

**UPDATE:**
You will also need to pass in the cartItems to the handleSubmit. This seems to be the way to do so:

```
const Checkout = ({ emoneyPayment, setEmoneyPayment, cartItems }: CheckoutProps) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<Order>();

  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const finalData = {...data, cartItems}
    alert(JSON.stringify(finalData));
    // do your actual submit stuff here
  };

  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>...formcomponents...</form>
}
```